# jquery animate simultaneous with 'html,body' scrolling/animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I'm trying to animate two things at the same time. one is

```js
var submenuHeight = parseInt($("#submenu").height());
console.log(submenuHeight);
var scrollOffset = parseInt($(window).scrollTop());
console.log(scrollOffset);
scrollOffset = scrollOffset - submenuHeight;
console.log(scrollOffset);
$("#submenu").animate({
  height: '18px'
}, {
  duration: 250,
  queue: false
});
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: scrollOffset
}, {
  duration: 250,
  queue: false
});
```

```html
<div id="submenu"></div>
```

the side then includes lots of text. I want to be able to close the menu but stay at the same piece of text, meaning animate the scrolling to the same part of the page.

but weirdly this animation does not work simultaneously even though I set queue to false. what might be going wrong?

Comment: But they both work, just not at the same time ?

Comment: yes. both do what they do. but they run one after the other....

Comment: Interestingly, I put this into a Fiddle, but changed the example to use two divs instead of trying to change the page scrollTop, and it animated simultaneously just fine. Perhaps the browser isn't updating it's view of the page during the scroll, or is locking additional javascript calls during the scroll, or something like that? Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7yw5p8p5/1/

Comment: could u post the code or send the link to the fiddle? I wanna see if I can use it for my needs also. problem is that I'm not scrolling to beginning of div but towards somewhere in the middle of it... but maybe your code would work?